# S3 Pre-Signed URL upload back-end validation post-upload

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I implemented file-upload through the pre-signed URL system on the front-end, however, I'm not sure how to validate the upload and update the database in a secure/consistent manner.

For instance, the only thing I get back from the upload is the URL with the key of the file. I then need to update my database and assign that key to the user who uploaded that file, via a POST request that would look something like this:

```
 await fetch("https://api.com/posts/completed/", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + auth.token,
        },
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          key: fileKey,
        }),
      })
```

Then on the back-end, I should probably try to get the S3 object, see if it actually exists, update the database with the new document and assign it to the user.

But what stops someone from abusing this and "messing up" with the fragility of this system?

If the file key is publicly available, someone could try to make a POST request to my server with the same key. As a consequence, I wonder if I should also do a DB check before creating the document, such as, `Post.findOne({content: key})`, and if it exists, return an error?

Any advice on how to proceed is deeply appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do - but if you want to "validate" uploaded objects in some way, you can create a Lambda that responds to new objects in the bucket using [S3 Event Notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html), then downloads the object, validates it and updates your database.

Comment: Yeah, use a Lambda based of an S3 notification to get the file from S3 after an upload, validate it, then place the validated copy somewhere else in S3 to use.  If someone uploads multiple copies, then fine, you validate multiple copies, if they upload a good image, then a bad image, you ignore the bad image.